# How to deal with name confilts in T-SQL filetables via subdirectories ON INSERT?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I encountered an issue with storing files in filetables, due to them having same filenames and thus violating the unique constraint. I decided to try and work around this, by adding new trigger into database ON INSERT, that would create new randomly named subdirectory, and then set it as a parent path.

I have found some examples of how this can be done by updating the row after writing, effectively moving the file. Is it possible to do this during the insert? I don't want to risk a situation where by any chance two files would attempt to use the same directory before moving into their own (since on files with same names, this causes a crash).

Basically and a BEFORE INSERT trigger that would:

1. INSERT statement

TRIGGER

2. create subdirectory
3. cset new parent_path

END

4. finish inserting

I know it can't be done by simply adding the parent_path_locator as it is computed value.
This code doesn't work. It was my first attempt (which i now know cant work due to computed property) and describes what i would like to do.

```
DECLARE @val table (id hierarchyid);
DECLARE @val2 hierarchyid;

INSERT INTO [fulladb].[mock___filetable]
        ([name]
        ,[is_directory]
        ,[is_archive]
)
    OUTPUT inserted.path_locator INTO @val
    VALUES
        ('ducken', 1, 0);

SELECT @val2 = id from @val;

INSERT INTO [fulladb].[mock___filetable]
        ([name]
        , [parent_path_locator]
        ,[is_directory]
        ,[is_archive]
)
    VALUES
        ('ducken_inner', @val2,1, 0)
GO
```

Comment: FWIW: When I've needed to keep track of files in a database I've used a [surrogate key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key), e.g. an `identity` column, to generate the name of the stored file while the table keeps the original filename. The files are then distributed into directories with no more than 1000 files each to avoid performance problems. (Easily done if you format `Id % 1000` for the directory and `Id / 1000` for the name with leading zeros.) Name collisions become an application issue, e.g. handling revisions of documents.

Comment: Not entirely clear what your use case is but file system is essentially a database. Simplest of its kind where keys are paths and values are byte strings.So we are talking synchronization issue between two databases. Let alone usability of triggers which may be super hard to test in concurrent world. Your friends are now, one writer/multiple readers or transactions or locking or, the best one, moving this entire logic away from database to server business logic.